# Looking for an analytical expression of this horror-integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integration, special-functions

I have given a function $$a(m,n,\mu,\nu,p):=\frac{2p+1}{2}\frac{(p-m-\mu)!}{(p+m+\mu)!}\int_{-1}^1 P^m_n(x)P^\mu_{\nu}(x)P^{m+\mu}_p(x)dx.$$
(of course all parameters are appropriate integers, so that everything behaves well).
The $P^m_n$ are associated Legendre polynomials.
The thing is that I want to compute this function in Matlab and I do not want to have an integral in there, hence I am looking for a nice solution of this.

If you do not have an idea how to solve it, but think that you know a way how to deal with this numerically better than solving numerically this integral, your answer is also HIGHLY APPRECIATED!

Comment: yes, you are right, added it..thanks

Comment: I know how I'd deal with this integral but besides being a rather obscene and rude way, I don't think you'd like it since it is completely mathematicsless...

Comment: @DonAntonio this makes me curious...

Comment: Well @Lipschitz, basically I'd vigorously curse the integral and whoever gave it to me, then I'd rip the paper/blackboard where it is written and then I'll go away to have a beer with some friends.

Comment: ahhhhh, thanks DonAntonio, sometimes i lose sight of the wood for the trees ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be helpful, no? Google is your friend!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomials#Gaunt.27s_formula

Comment: Actually, I read this article(honestly!) but somehow I must have overlooked this. THANK YOU A 1000 TIMES!

Comment: No worries mate. Seemed almost too good to be true, I'm guessing whoever gave you that question knew about it.